# How to find a directed path in NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

So. I'm trying to find paths through a directed graph.

I start out with a Pandas data frame with 3 columns: 'Source', 'Target', 'weight.' The weight is used to keep track of the action of each target (it's just a number).

Then I convert the df into an edge list:

> edge_list = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Source','Target','weight')

Then for good measure, I convert *this* into a directed graph (and I'm fairly confident this is happening correctly)

> directed_graph = nx.DiGraph(edge_list)

However, whenever I start to search for paths within the graphs, I'm getting undirected paths. I checked and double-checked but if I define a path

> path = nx.shortest_path(directed_graph,source=A,target=B,weight='weight')

the *path* that's returned can't be found by following the directed paths found in the graph. (It can, however be found by following undirected paths, so I guess that's something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can direclty create your digraph by specifying  `create_using=nx.DiGraph()`

```
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Source','Target','weight', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

`nx.from_pandas_edgelist` returns an instance of a graph, not an edge list, so you are first creating a graph and then converting it to a digraph by adding two directed arcs `(i,j)`, `(j,i)` for each undirected edge `(i,j)`.

Example:

```
>>> g=nx.from_edgelist([(1,2),(3,4)])
>>> g.edges()
EdgeView([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
>>> nx.DiGraph(g).edges()
OutEdgeView([(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 3)])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed my problem.

Comment: Okay, so follow-up, because this created a second problem. Now I'm trying to find a path I know exists, but nx.has_path() is returning False.